# Google Analytics: Filtes query include only homepage with subdirectory

Tags: google-analytics, regex

I want to create a Regex query to filter only the homepage with some subcategories.
I have multi-language home pages with the this structure:

- `mail.example.com/en/`
- `example.com/`
- `example.com/de/categoy/bla-bla-bla/`
- `example.com/fr/categoy/bla-bla-bla/`
- `example.com/en/category/category/bla-bla-bla/`
- `example.com/fr/`
- `subdomain.example.com/`
- `subdomain.example.com/bla-bla-bla/`
- `example.ua/en/news/video/bla-bla-bla/`

So, I'm trying to include only all home pages with different languages and using RegEx for it as
`^example\.com\/((fr|en|de)\/)?$`

The regex101.com showed that my expressions working well, but in Google Analytics I have some data from content pages as `example.ua/en/news/video/bla-bla-bla/` and cant exclude it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is fine, but it won't match the field that you are filtering against.  You are filtering against `Hostname` which is always going to be either `example.com` or `example.ua`.  It will never have URL path after it.  Your rule is always going to match.

Instead you should be filtering against the `Request URI`.  From the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034380?hl=en&ref_topic=1034830#zippy=%2Ccontent-and-traffic):

> **Request URI** -- Includes the relative URL, or piece of the URL after the hostname. For example: for `http://www.google-analytics.com/requestURL/index.html?sample=text` the Request URI is `/requestURL/index.html?sample=text`

Then your filter pattern shouldn't include the domain name.  It should just be:

```
^\/((fr|en|de)\/)?$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for discribing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for describing. I tried to use this expression and found that subdomains are included. So I need something for excluding subdomain.example.com. And I choose ^example\.com\/((ru|en|fr)\/)?$ for Request URI. And its not working. Im thinking, that google is not good with RegEx. Also, I'm using hostname, because a have one filter that include Full URL

Comment: Google Analytics doesn't have a field that contains both of those pieces of information, nor a filter mechanism to filter against two or more fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Your expressions work well. I just need to remove the second filter Full URL and all data started to collect good. Have a good day!